# Flask - Limiting a user to a single device

Tags: python, flask, oauth, ldap

I'm new to Flask and I'm creating a web application that has a login (integrated with Azure AD).

I'm trying to ensure that a particular user, once logged in on a device, cannot access the application through another device with the same ID, unless he/she logs out of the first device.

Alternatively, if a user tries to login with a new device, he/she can get logged out of all existing devices before logging in to the new device.

Is this possible with `flask_login`?

Comment: This feature requires additional device registration and management functionality as well as a client side implementation. Your question is too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Generally you can store a validation in a database and check any session cockie against it (I don't think flask does that by default, maybe flask login), then when a user logs in, disable all other session owned by him. That way whenever the user logs in on another device, all other devices are logged out.

Comment: @syntonym, that was what I had in mind. But, a database access on every refresh is very expensive, right? Is there a way that I could do this in-memory? I went through the flask-login documentation, but I couldn't find anything which could help me.

Comment: @shreyashk Whether you do this via a databse or any other memory store (e.g. a dict in python) doesn't really matter for the feature. Ofcourse if you use a dict or similar you must take care of multithreading/processing etc. depending on how you deploy. Maybe something like redis? Alternatively set a short living cookie which does not need to get check on every page reload and a long living one for refreshing the session (basically flask_login's remember me functionality).

Comment: Won't this implementation lead to an issue where expired sessions may still be alive in the database? Is there a flask method to forcibly cause a particular session to expire, where I could add a cleanup method?